# Active nav item doesn't switch until you scroll past the anchor target

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am using navbar-fixed-top and when scroll down the page, the active nav item doesn't switch until you scroll past the anchor target.

This is happening because the browser is waiting until the anchor target "hits" the top of the page before changing the active nav item. I want the active nav item to change when the anchor target reaches the bottom of my navbar.

No preference when it comes to format (will accept any solution) and please DO NOT post anything that has to do with padding... all that does is push the webpage down however many pixels... this is not the solution I am looking for.

```css
/* BOOTSTRAP 3.x GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */

body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
/* NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */

.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #763f8d;
  border-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
  background-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
  background-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ecdbff;
}
/* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */

.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/* Jumbotron
-------------------------------------------------- */

.jumbotron {}
/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Pad the edges of the mobile views a bit */

.marketing {
  padding-top: 75px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
}
/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */

.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#team-btn {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0;
  /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}
.featurette {
  padding-top: 120px;
  /* Vertically center images part 1: add padding above and below text. */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Vertically center images part 2: clear their floats. */
}
.featurette-image {
  margin-top: -120px;
  /* Vertically center images part 3: negative margin up the image the same amount of the padding to center it. */
}
/* Give some space on the sides of the floated elements so text doesn't run right into it. */

.featurette-image.pull-left {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.featurette-image.pull-right {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
/* Thin out the marketing headings */

.featurette-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
/* Footer
-------------------------------------------------- */

hr {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
}
footer {}
/* Responsive CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Navigation */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ecdbff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ecdbff;
    background-color: #5e2d73;
  }
}
/* Marketing */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .marketing {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="0" id="home">
  <header>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="navtop" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The James Baldwin School</a>
          </div>

          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

              <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#faculty">Faculty</a>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Parents <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Students <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Teachers <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--- /.navbar-collapse collapse --->

        </div>
        <!--- /#navtop --->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar wrapper -->
  </header>

  <!--- JAMES-BALDWIN ========================================================
============================================================================ --->

  <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Baldwin" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1757925/thumbs/o-JAMES-BALDWIN-facebook.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </a>
  <div class="image-caption">

  </div>

  <!--- JUMBOTRON ============================================================
============================================================================ --->

  <div class="jumbotron" id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>The James Baldwin School</h1>
        <h2>A School For Expeditionary Learning.</h2>
        <p>It is our mission to provide a philosophical and practical education for all students, an education that features creativity and inquiry, encourages habitual reading and productivity, as well as self-reflection and original thought. We agree with
          Socrates that the “unexamined life is not worth living,” and it is our desire to prepare students to live thoughtful and meaningful lives. We are committed to inspiring the love of learning in our students.</p>
        <p>It is our mission, as well, at the James Baldwin School, to provide a haven for students who have previously experienced school as unresponsive to their needs as individuals. We wish for all students to find their voice and to speak knowledgeably
          and thoughtfully on issues that concern their school, their world. We aid students in this endeavor by personalizing our learning situations, by democratizing and humanizing the school environment, and by creating a “talking culture,” an atmosphere
          of informal intellectual discourse among students and faculty.</p>
        <p>Democratizing the school would be impossible without our Core Values. Our core values help students aquire the important skills needed to continue their journey through life. Most importantly, our core values maintain safety and democracy for
          students and faculty.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="#">Learn more about Core Values</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes ===================================
============================================================================ -->

  <div class="container marketing" id="faculty">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
        <h2>Brady Smith</h2>
        <p>Principal Co-Director</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
        <h2>Josh Heisler</h2>
        <p>Teacher Co-Director</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
        <h2>Christine Olsen</h2>
        <p>Admissions</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
        <h2>Brady Smith</h2>
        <p>Principal Co-Director</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
        <h2>Josh Heisler</h2>
        <p>Teacher Co-Director</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
        <h2>Christine Olsen</h2>
        <p>Admissions</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <div id="team-btn">
      <div class="text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="#">See the rest of Our Team</a>
      </div>
      <!--- /.text-center --->
    </div>
    <!--- /.team-btn --->


    <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->



    <!--- /END THE FEATURETTES --->

  </div>
  <!-- /.container marketing -->

  <!-- FOOTER -->

  <hr>

  <div class="container">
    <footer class="text-center" id="footer">
      <p>This site was created by Isaac Perez.<a href="#"> Back to top.</a>
      </p>
      <p>Copyright 2014 &copy; The James Baldwin School.
        <br>Some Rights Reserved</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <!--- Javascript Bootsrap --->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my last answer, I have made a webpage including Scrollspy and as my old answer was not very useful, I replaced it. In the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) for Scrollspy, one of the options listed is data-offset which you can easily use by just adding it to the element you're spying on, in your case the body. In the code above this attribute is already there, you just need to change the value:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="70" id="home">
<!-- I have found 70px to work well, but you can fiddle around with it to get what you're after -->
```

Comment: Perfect, but only works (how I want) when scrolling from "Home" to "About" should I edit the ID in data-spy?

Comment: @xXDarksnakeXx In short, no. The `data-spy` attribute tells Bootstrap what JavaScript plugin you want to use eg. Scrollspy, Affix, etc... Could you please change your snippet above so that it includes the `data-offset="70"` I mentioned above so that I can see what the problem is with the other tabs? I would also encourage you to read the documentation for Scrollspy at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: Check out the fiddle.. I believe snippets should still be in BETA phase :D

http://jsfiddle.net/xXDarksnakeXx/409tfas4/embedded/result/

Comment: I'm sure it's because div class "container marketing" doesn't start where "jumbotron" ends. if you have an editor that shows visual representations of containers (like Brackets) then you'll be able to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/Tugzrida/xhLo5o9n/embedded/result/ It seems to be working for me. First I changed the `data-offset` from 50px to 51px as that made the transition from home to about more accurate. I have also fixed between about and faculty. The problem was that by default in bootstrap, the jumbotron has 30 px of bottom margin. I just added the following to the css: `.jumbotron {margin-bottom: 0px;}` PS Thanks for mentioning Brackets, It's my new favourite editor, I was using Gedit.